# Analog of Green’s Functions for a Vector Potential

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

A friend of mine recently asked me to help him with magnetostatics, and his question led me to consider the plausibility of an analogous form to Green’s functions for a scalar potential.

I have not yet taken a rigorous undergraduate electro/magnetostatics course, but in my partial differential equations course I was taught that a formal way of solving a charge distribution through “image charges” was by using Green’s Functions.

Green’s Functions are defined for a dirichlet problem in 2 dimensions as follows,

$$ G(x,y) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \left ( \frac{1}{\left\| y - x \right\|} \right ) + h^{*}(y)$$

where $h^{*}$ solves

$$ \nabla^2 h^{*} = 0 \qquad in \quad \Omega $$
$$ h^{*}(y) = - \frac{1}{2 \pi} \ln \left ( \frac{1}{\left\| y - x \right\|} \right ) \qquad on \quad \partial \Omega $$

I am curious if there is an analogous form of this for a vector potential problem, such as $$ \nabla \times A = 0 $$ on $ \partial \Omega $.

Thank you

Comment: You'll need to typeset your working using Latex because it's not particularly easy to read.

Comment: @mattos done, sorry.